# Let $f$ be a function such that $|f(x)| \leq x^2$ for all $x$ on a neighborhood of $0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and calculate $f'(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined on a neighborhood of $0$ with the property that $|f(x)| \leq x^2$ for all $x$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and calculate $f'(0)$.

I have started this problem by first letting $I$ be a neighborhood of $0$. Then I let $x$ be an element of $I\backslash \{0\}$. I am pretty sure $I$ then must show the limit exists and evaluate it at $0$. However, I am not sure how to show it is defined at $0$ with just the fact that $|f(x)| ≤ x^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: FYI a neighborhood of zero includes zero.

Comment: @MD3 Do you know that the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"? Please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0) = 0$, since $f(0) = 0$ you have to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = 0.
$$

Comment: How do we know that f(0)=0 as the problem only states that |f(x)|<x^2?

Comment: @lj_growl The problem actually states $|f(x)|\le x^2$

Comment: If $|f(x)| \leq x^2$, then $|f(0)| \leq 0$, i.e. $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Rigel could you show this by dividing by x and then taking the limit from the inequality?

Comment: Just take $x=0$; by assumption, the inequality holds in a neighborhood of $0$ (hence also at $0$).